# App crashes on login, crash when starting dashboard activity

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple login to dashboard app and I'm having trouble with my app launching as I try to launch the dashboard home activity once login is tapped with correct credentials.

```
error code: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.david.myview3/com.example.david.myview3.DashBoardAppActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

It is the DashBoardAppActivity.java I wish to launch which happens in the the signIn() method of this class.

```
public void signIn(View V)
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");                        

    // get the Refferences of views
    final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
    final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

    Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

    // Set On ClickListener
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get The User name and Password
            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

            // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
            String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

            // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
            if(password.equals(storedPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashBoardAppActivity.class));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

DashBoardAppActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public abstract class DashboardAppActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    //Lifecycle Methods

    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    //App Click Methods

    public void onSearch(View v)
    {
        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class));
    }

    public void onAbout(View v)
    {
        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class));
    }

    public void return2Home(Context context)
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity (intent);
    }

    public void onPhotoAlbum(View v)
    {
        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotoAlbumActivity.class));
    }

    public void onMessage(View v)
    {
        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagesActivity.class));
    }

    public void onHome (View v)
    {
        return2Home(this);
    }

}
```

And this is my manifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.david.myview3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DashHomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            />

        <activity
        android:name="SignUPActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/title_search"/>

        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/title_about"
            />
        <activity android:name=".PhotoAlbumActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/title_photoalbum"
            />
        <activity android:name=".MessagesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/title_message"
            />



</application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />





</manifest>
```

This activity launches fine if I launch one of it's features before it then use said features home feature to return to the dashbaord, it just does not seem to like to go from login to that dashboard first.

Comment: DashBoardAppActivity add in menifest file.

Comment: can you add DashBoardAppActivity code ?.

Comment: @Dave95 did you find solution for it?

Comment: no i did not, just got home after being away with work sorry, i've added my dashboardAppActivity code to try find the issue

Answer (score 0):

DashBoardAppActivity is not defined in android Manifest.xml
It should be something like this

```
<activity android:name=".DashBoardAppActivity "
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            />
```

Comment: when i do this is says that it isnt a concrete class so error. It's abstract so this is likely the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this  DashBoardAppActivity activity to manifest

```
        <activity android:name=".DashBoardAppActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
       />
```

Comment: when i do this is says that it isnt a concrete class so error. It's abstract so this is likely the issue?

Comment: it is abstract class you dont need to register it, in system uses classes which can be called by intent below is the link please see it

Comment: is there any another class which extends DashboardAppActivity